# how to understand the output of "echo $-"?

Tags: bash, variable

How to understand the output of `echo $-`? It looks like some kind of flag characters. I can't get a clue by googling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They represent the values of the shell's flags; this is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02):

> `-`
>
> (Hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags (the single-letter option names concatenated into a string) as specified on invocation, by the `set` special built-in command, or implicitly by the shell.

The [Zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) mentions it briefly:

> **-** <S> Flags supplied to the shell on invocation or by the `set` or `setopt` commands.

as does the [Bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN%C2%A0COMMANDS) in the description of `set`:

> The current set of options may be found in `$-`.

To understand the output of `echo $-` you need to look up the options in your shell's manual. For example, in Bash, `echo $-` outputs `himBHs` for me, which means that the `-h`, `-m`, `-B` and `-H` options are enabled (see `help set` for details), that the shell is interactive (`-i`) and reading from standard input (`-s`).

Comment: how to search builtin command? for example, `man set`.

Comment: Use "/" to search. You're probably looking for `man bash`, or `help set` as mentioned earlier, rather than `man set`.

Comment: Any idea what the `c` flag means? I see it set when rsync logs in and runs my .bashrc. The bash manual for `set` doesn't mention `c`. I'm running bash 4.2.46(2)-release.

Comment: @Andrew it reflects the `-c` command-line option; see `bash -c 'echo $-'`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html):

> set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]
>
> Without options, the name and value of each shell variable are displayed in a format that can be reused as input for setting or resetting  the       currently-set  variables.
>
> ...
>
> The  options are off by default unless otherwise noted.  Using + rather than - causes these options to be turned off.  The options can also be specified as arguments to an invocation of the shell.  **The current set of options may be found in $-.**  The return status is always true unless an invalid option is encountered.