# How to display all the shell attributes for current shell session?

Tags: bash, shell

According to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/821094/what-is-the-difference-between-set-env-declare-and-export-when-setting-a-varia),

1. environment variables
2. shell variables
3. shell attributes

are 3 totally different things.

In that thread, 1 and 2 can be displayed with `env` and `set`, respectively.

How to display all the last one `shell attributes` for current shell session?

Comment: You mean shell options?

Comment: @Inian I am not sure. I am quite new to linux shell. In that link, it literally says `shell attributes`, which governs how shell works.

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: `typeset -p` will tell you all the variables with their *attributes* (`declare -x` for exported variables, `declare -i` for integer/numeric variables, etc). The `BASHOPTS` variable contains the options set with `shopt`, and the `SHELLOPTS` the options set with `set -o`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$-` will give you the currently-set shell options:

```
echo $-
```

See [how to understand the output of "echo $-"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315829/86440) for references.

Additionally, in Bash, `shopt` will show you the current settings governing [optional shell behaviour](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).